# jQuery: fadeOut then slideDown

Tags: jquery

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

```
button Contact (on click)
  |
  |--> 1. div .buttons (fadeOut)
  |
  |--> 2. div .toggle (slideDown)


button Cancel (on click)
  |
  |--> 1. div .toggle (slideUp)
  |
  |--> 2. div .buttons (fadeIn)
```

How can I achieve this using jQuery? **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/Hx65Q/1376/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a callback or a deferred with [$.when](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/). Here's one solution:

```
$(".contact").click(function() {
    var deferred = $(".toggle").slideDown(200);
    $.when(deferred).done(function() {
        $(".buttons").fadeOut(200);
    });
});

$(".cancel").click(function() {
    var deferred = $(".toggle").slideUp(200);
    $.when(deferred).done(function() {
        $(".buttons").fadeIn(200);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks mate! That's exactly what I was trying to do.